# How to add features from 2 .csv files into X_train

Tags: pandas, csv, machine-learning

I have several .csv files with house data from four different districts:

1. Duckez.csv:
   [image]
2. coordinate.csv:
   [image]

So the result I want that is to gather features into a numpy array `X_train` so that the model can be train and predict the house price for an unknown given latitude and longtitude ( coordinate )
The target `X_train` that I want contains these features: Bedrooms,Gardens,Latitude, Longitude (depending on the name of the .csv file, for example all the data from Duckez.csv file when merging will contain the latitude and longtitude of Dukez).

There are 4 similar .csv file: Duckez.csv, Vim.csv, Hustla.csv, Zedrim.csv

Answer (score 0):

1. Read your 'coordinate.csv' into a dataframe called `coords` with `pd.read_csv`
2. For the house records (`houses`), we'll want one large dataframe. Declare it with an extra column 'District'. ('District' should be a categorical)

   - write a for-loop `for district in ['Duckez', 'Vim',' Hustla', 'Zedrim']`:
     that does the following
   - read the 'Duckez.csv' in with `pd.read_csv` and set 'District' = 'Duckez'..., etc.
   - you might want to `pd.concat([dataframes], axis=0)`. You could do all this in one line with a list comprehension, if you wanted to be fancy.
   - in your read_csv command, you can specify the dtype of each column
3. Then `pd.join` these `houses` and `coords`, on the 'District' column. This gives you one final dataframe `df` or `recs` or whatever.

   - see [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101/)
   - use the `df.info()` command, make sure the dtypes are correct.
4. Finally for mungeing all the int,float,string,categorical data from `recs` into a strictly numerical (int/float)-only array `X_train` for training ML, there's tons of examples, beginner blogs, boilerplate out there, look for it. Also commonly do any NA-filling, or transforms (e.g. normalizing) here. And computing any derived features (e.g. `Bathroom_to_Bedroom_Ratio`, `SqFt_per_Bedrooms`, etc.)

Now try to write your own code to do this, it's not hard. (On SO, you're supposed to post your own code attempt, not just a spec and ask for code.) Edit your own code attempt into your question, people are much more likely to answer questions showing the OP's code.

Ok, roll your sleeves up and start writing the code. Refer to blogs and SO when stuck.